# Swift - objectForKey in Dictionary without using dict[key] syntax

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

This can't be a difficult thing to do, but no matter how I word this question while searching I always end up with the `dict[key]` syntax.

I want to know how to perform something similar to the objective-c `objectForKey` on a swift Dictionary. I understand that I can do it like this:

```
 var value = myDict[key]
```

But that's not what I want. I can't find a method on Dictionary that works similarly to the obj-c objectForKey. Something like:

```
var value = myDict.objectForKey(key)
```

I know some of the Dictionary methods got weird names in Swift, like append rather than addObject. What's the weird name for this one? I scanned the Dictionary class but didn't see anything that stuck out to me.

Comment: You say that you want something that works similarly to the obj-c objectForKey. But your swift example _does_ work similarly to the objectForKey. Is there a reason you don't want to use myDict[key]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using a Swift Dictionary. If you want to use the obj-c method style, you should use `NSDictionary`. (Swift Dictionary and `NSDictionary` are not the same).

Once you have `NSDictionary` object, you can call obj-c methods on it, like

```
myDict.objectForKey(aKey)
```

More helpt at [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectForKey:).